# Component is rendered before i can redirect the route. How can I mitigate rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to route through 3 sites. Login - Dashboard - Details
Details is based on data selection in Dashboard.
If I refresh the url/Details site, the context is lost and i would like to redirect to Dashboard, but Details is throwing erros before i can redirect. How can I change this behaviour?

I've tried the following approaches without success:
1. redirection in the Browserrouter based on if the necessary data exists, if not redirect to Dashboard
2. Within Details componentWillMount() I have set up a redirect

Do I really need to check every data usage if data exists? This seems like quite a hassle for simple routing...

This is my routing configuration. The second redicrect doesn't work.

```
            {this.props.token?<Redirect to="/dashboard" />:<Redirect to="/login" />}
            {this.props.selectedCow?<Redirect to="/dashboard"/>:null}
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/details" component={CowDetails} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
```

Error: Data is not defined (CowDetails is rendered and context is missing before redirection)

Comment: It would be nice if you provided actual snippets or examples of code you have tried.

Comment: @versvs ive added my routing snippet

Answer (score 0):

I was using Redirect in the wrong way. As specified in the Docs it actually works without rendering the component.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

So for me it is

```
<Route exact path="/details" render={() => (
                    this.props.selectedCow ? (
                      {CowDetails}

                    ) : (
                      <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
                    )
                  )}/>
```